# How can I open source code for an Android app?

Tags: java, android, ide

I am following along with TeamTreeHouse's android development tutorial. They provide the source code for each lesson along with a tutorial of how to follow along.

I would like to skip ahead a little bit to see what it's like to run the final product.

I have the source code, but I don't know how to open the code as an android app that I can run in an IDE, make edits to, and see changes.

How can I go about this? I currently have Android Studio, Eclipse, IntelliJ, as well as the Eclipse-based IDE that TeamTreeHouse provides.

EDIT: Solution found. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vbAVbqERIz8

Comment: have you tried reading the tutorial? I imagine thats probably one of the parts they teach you, so skipping ahead might not be in your best interests.

Comment: Nope, they show you what to do step by step, but never go over how to build it from the source... I've gone through already over half of the tutorial and they haven't mentioned how. I've also done other tutorials from this site and they don't go over it. It's sometimes helpful to check individual files but I haven't figured out how to run the whole thing. It's the ide that's giving me problems, and the fact that I'm new to Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about android studio, but if you go into eclipse, go to File > Import, then select "import existing android code into workspace", and choose the source code folder. Be sure to check "Copy project files into workspace". Then, you need to be sure you have the latest android SDK, ADT plugin, and a working android emulator (in eclipse). Goodluck!